# Android-how to capture picture of constant size 8.5 x 11 inches on android at 200 to 300 dpi?

Tags: android, image, constants, image-size

I want to capture image of size 8.5 inch(width) and 11 inch (height) from the android device having 5 mp camera which is has highest resolution 2592 x 1944 pixels.

Comment: can't you set resolution in your camera? in settings, it has.

Comment: I want this through code .